# Iteration not working properly

Tags: javascript

I have several for loops. However my last for loop doesn't work as expected. for ( code_string in match) it is supposed to go through each code in my match string.

For example, my output should be :

```
  Initial Programming One-time Charge   $9.1

  Monthly Cost  $2.65
```

But for some reason that I do not see I am getting 9.1 for both.

I have attached a picture for better understanding.
[image]

```html
    for (var key in t.data.codes_prices_array) {

      for (code in code_to_match) {
    
   // for ( code_string in match){
           //if 251 == 251 
        if (code_to_match[code] == c.data.codes_prices_array[key].u_charge_code) {
     console.log("code to match", code_to_match[code], "u_charge_code", c.data.codes_prices_array[key].u_charge_code);
      for ( code_string in match){
     //if it is not blank or doesn't have a price of 0 (changed 2013-2-6)
     if ( c.data.codes_prices_array[key].u_price!= '' && c.data.codes_prices_array[key] != 0){
      strVal = strVal.replace(match[code_string], "$" + c.data.codes_prices_array[key].u_price);
       t.data.u_pricing = strVal;
      console.log("MONTHLY PRICE", match[code_string], "$" + c.data.codes_prices_array[key].u_price);
     }
     else{
      strVal = strVal.replace(match[code_string], "$" + c.data.codes_prices_array[key].u_one_time_charge);
       t.data.u_pricing = strVal;
      console.log("ONE TIME ", match[code_string], "$" + c.data.codes_prices_array[key].u_one_time_charge);
     }

        }
    }
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you have the correct expected results in your logs, the problem is not with the loop itself (although I suspect there may be a more efficient way of tackling this) but rather with the way you're populating the results.  If you provide of the code used to actually populate the DOM it should be possible to pinpoint what the problem is.